# Perform an action over 2 and 2 elements in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers, say

```
data = [45,34,33,20,16,13,12,3]
```

I'd like to compute the difference between 2 and 2 items, (that is, for the above data
I want to compute 45-34,33-20,16-13 and 12-3, what's the python way of doing that ?

Also, more generally, how should I apply a function to 2 and 2 of these elements, that is, I want to call `myfunc(data[0],data[1]),myfunc(data[2],data[3])` and so on over the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try slicing the list:

```
from itertools import izip
[myfunc(a, b) for a, b in izip(data[::2], data[1::2])]
```

or you can use the fact that izip guarantees the order in which it consumes its arguments:

```
idata = iter(data)
[myfunc(a, b) for a, b in izip(idata, idata)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own iterator to iterate over the elements two-by-two:

```
class myiter(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        a = self.l.next()
        b = self.l.next()
        return (a, b)
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = iter(l)
```

The iterator returns tuples of two elements at a time:

```
>>> for x, y in i(data):
...     print x, y
45 34
33 20
16 13
12 3
```

Then you can use it to map your function:

```
>>> [myfunc(x, y) for x, y in myiter(data)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def pairs(iterable):
    while iterable:
        yield next(iterable),next(iterable)

data = [45,34,33,20,16,13,12,3]
print "With pairs generator"
print ','.join(str(a-b) for a,b in pairs(iter(data)))
```

Consuming version (data will be removed from the list, so take copy if still needed), "without comprehension".

```
print 'By simple list pop way'
data_c = data[:]
result=[]
while data_c: result.append(data_c.pop(0)-data_c.pop(0))
print result
```

I would use generally list comprehensions and slicing, but these solutions are maybe sometimes more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import tee,izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

for a,b in pairwise(data):
    print a-b
```

Requires Python 2.6 or later. I took `pairwise()` from [here](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

Comment: OP doesn't want `pairwise`, but `grouper`.

Comment: Nice as code, though different function as has overlapping pairs.

Answer (score 1):

```
diffs = [data[i] - data[i+1] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]
```

or the general case

```
pairs = [(data[i], data[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]
results = [myfunc(*p) for p in pairs]
```

Not as elegant as some of the other solutions maybe. Still this ought to be mentioned.